# CakePHP won't redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, controller

I'm getting these weird messages while working in CakePHP whenever I'm using a controller function that executes and redirects

```
Query: check 

Query: setFlash 

Query: write
```

Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Could you post some code from your controller functions that's actually calling `$this->redirect()`?

Comment: I found the problem, I was dumb enough to declare a model called Session, so when I used CakePHP Session helper it took it as if it were my Session object. So when I did $this->Session->action() it would output it as a Query

Comment: you should put that in an answer, then accept your own answer as the solution, because this question is showing up on the "Unanswered" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I declared a model called Session, so when I used CakePHP Session helper it took it as if it were my Session object. So when I did `$this->Session->action()` it would output it as a Query